# jquery get select text from the page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a chrome extension for windows, that copies any selected text from the page to the clipboard.I am using jquery for doing the java script part.

How can i get any selected/highlighted text in that page? To put it in other way,is there an event listener, that gets triggered when any portion of text is highlighted.

Comment: see http://supermig.free.fr/jagui/TextSelectionEvent/ It was the first result on google for `ontextselect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getSelected() {
  if (window.getSelection) return window.getSelection();
  if (document.getSelection) return document.getSelection();
  if (document.selection) return document.selection.createRange().text;
}

document.onmouseup = function () {
  getSelected(); // => "Something you've sele..."
};
```

---

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/mU8UE/)

Comment: +1,Great answer, one small edit , can i change it 'click' instead of mousemove as it causes way too much calls the method

Comment: Try that: `document.onmouseup = getSelText;`

Answer (score 3):

The best so far i have experiences with is using **[zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/)** and manually attach the selected text to it using `document.selection.createRange().text` or  `window.getSelection()`

usage: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions

This should give you a good start:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/utobes/2/edit)*

```
var highlighted;
$(document).on('mouseup', function(e){     
   if (window.getSelection) {
      highlighted  = window.getSelection();
   } else if (document.selection) {
      highlighted = document.selection.createRange();
   }        
   var selectedText = highlighted.toString() !=='' && highlighted;
  
   alert(selectedText); // to be added to clipboard
});
```